# scipy.integrate.ode, issue with function returning tuple

Tags: numpy, scipy, ode, integrator

So I've written a function to use a particular solver type to integrate a couple system of ODEs. For some reason, which I can't quite get a handle on, the function I wrote to define the RHS of the ODE is returning a tuple when run inside the integrating function (or so the error indicates), but whenever I test the array it returns separately, the array seems to be...well... and array, which is supposed to work fine.

```
def solve_decay_system(t, u_0, solver_type="dopri5", K_1=0.0, K_2=0.0, K_3=0.0):

    def decay(u, K_1 = K_1, K_2=K_2, K_3=K_3):

        dydt = numpy.array([-K_1 * u[0], K_1 * u[0] - K_2 * u[1], K_2 * u[1] - K_3*u[2], K_3*u[2]])
        dydt = numpy.array(dydt)
        print dydt, type(dydt)
        return dydt
        #return [1, 2, 3, 4]

    u = numpy.empty((4, t.size))
    u_0 = numpy.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    u[0, 0] = u_0[0]
    u[1, 0] = u_0[1]
    u[2, 0] = u_0[2]
    u[3, 0] = u_0[3]

    integrator = integrate.ode(decay)
    integrator.set_integrator(solver_type)
    integrator.set_initial_value(u[:, 0])
    integrator.set_f_params(u, K_1, K_2, K_3)

    for (n, t_n) in enumerate(t[1:]):
        print n
        integrator.integrate(t_n)
        if not integrator.successful():
            break

        u[:, n + 1] = integrator.y


    return u
```

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this would be very helpful. Here is the resultant error, for reference:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-230-8f9be46c3d95> in <module>()
----> 1 solve_decay_system(t, u_0, solver_type="dopri5", K_1=0.0, K_2=0.0,     K_3=0.0)

<ipython-input-229-a05ddca0f334> in solve_decay_system(t, u_0, solver_type,     K_1, K_2, K_3)
     24     for (n, t_n) in enumerate(t[1:]):
     25         print n
---> 26         integrator.integrate(t_n)
     27         if not integrator.successful():
     28             break

C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ode.pyc in     integrate(self, t, step, relax)
    409         except SystemError:
    410             # f2py issue with tuple returns, see ticket 1187.
--> 411             raise ValueError('Function to integrate must not return     a tuple.')
    412 
    413         return self._y

ValueError: Function to integrate must not return a tuple.
```

Comment: With what input would you call `solve_decay_system`?

Comment: I call it thusly:    `t = numpy.linspace(0.0, 10.0, 10)
u_0 = numpy.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])


solve_decay_system(t, u_0, solver_type="dopri5", K_1=0.0, K_2=0.0, K_3=0.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative function expects `(time, state,...)` as first arguments,

```
def decay(t, u, K_1 = K_1, K_2=K_2, K_3=K_3):
```

even if the ODE is autonomous.

The state is not a parameter, esp. if you give the list of states as parameter.

```
  integrator.set_f_params(K_1, K_2, K_3)
```

With these changes your code should run. (Up to `n=8`.)

Even if you just return a list

```
def decay(t, u, K_1 = K_1, K_2=K_2, K_3=K_3):
    return  [-K_1 * u[0], K_1 * u[0] - K_2 * u[1], K_2 * u[1] - K_3*u[2], K_3*u[2]]
```